# Как динамически обращаться к обьекту в JS?

Tags: javascript

Имеется объект типа:

```
var data = {
price: 120,
monthly_fee: 10,
promotion: {price: 90, monthly_fee: 7.5}
};
```

Когда есть какой-то промоушн на сайте, объект promotion заполнен информацией с пересчитанной стоимостью услуг, если промо нету, он пуст.

Страница с оплатой заполняется всегда из этого объекта, и информацию берет либо по пути data.price, data.monthly_fee, либо data.promotion....

Как написать красиво код, чтобы не дублировать заполнение хтмл элементов в иф элс. То есть, примитивное решение:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty('promotion') && Object.keys(data.promotion).length > 0) {
    priceObj.val(data.promotion.price);
    monthlyFeeObj.val(data.promotion.monthly_fee);
} else { 
    // тут понятно думаю
}
```

Также, есть решение за которое зажают на пики точенные, и еще сами знаете на что:

```
var prefix = *promotion* ? '.promotion' : '';
var planInfo = eval('data' + prefix);
```

Как лучше всего реализовать эту задачу? В реале в объекте порядка 10 полей, и дублирование 10 строк кода в иф элс выглядит ужасно. Используется не в одном месте.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
  price: 120,
  monthly_fee: 10,
  promotion: {price: 90, monthly_fee: 7.5}
};

function FinalPriceValues(anInput) {
  var hasPromotion = anInput.hasOwnProperty('promotion') && Object.keys(anInput.promotion).length > 0;

  return {
    price: hasPromotion? anInput.promotion.price : anInput.price;
    monthly_fee: hasPromotion? anInput.promotion.monthly_fee : anInput.monthly_fee;
  };

  // или, если изменений в data не ожидается:

  return hasPromotion? anInput.promotion : anInput;
}

var finalPrices = FinalPriceValues(data);
priceObj.val(finalPrices.price);
monthlyFeeObj.val(finalPrices.monthly_fee);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```js
var data = {
  price: 120,
  monthly_fee: 10,
  price2: 110,
  promotion: {
    price: 90,
    monthly_fee: 7.5
  }
};
var proxy = new Proxy(data, {
  get: function(target, property) {
    return target.promotion[property] || target[property];
  }
});

console.log("price: ", proxy.price);
console.log("monthly_fee: ", proxy.monthly_fee);
console.log("price2: ", proxy.price2);
```